# How can I use LabelEncoder in Netflix data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data (movie in Netflix), it contains 3 columns movieId, title, and genres
each movie it can be classified into two or more genres for example:

```
    movieId             title                                       genres
0        1  Toy Story (1995)  Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
```

I want to put each genre in a split column
I started by creat new column by this code:

```
movie['types']= movie.genres.str.split( pat='|')
```

then I use LabeEncoder but it doesn't work
how can I reach my goal????